# php check that the $_POST sent are allowed fields

Tags: php, arrays, validation, post

I'm working on code to validate that all the $_POST variables are within an 'allowed' list to prevent hacking.

The idea is that if I have 4 fields in a form and someone send an additional post variable an error is shown.

My first question is: is that useful?

This is my PHP code to check the post sent, but I don't know why it doesn't work:

```
$allowed = array(
    'field1',
    'field2',
    'select1',
    'textarea1',
    'submit_button'
);

foreach($_POST as $k => $v) { 
    if(!array_key_exists($k, $allowed)) {
        die('error with field: '.$k);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `in_array` instead of `array_key_exists`

```
$allowed = array(
    'field1',
    'field2',
    'select1',
    'textarea1',
    'submit_button'
); 
foreach($_POST as $k => $v) { 
    if(!in_array($k, $allowed)) {
        die('error with field: '.$k);
    }
}
```

This can be useful, but you should perform **real** validation of received form anyway.

Comment: thanks in_array() works! yes of course this is before the real validation of all the fields. It is useful for you or can I avoid it?

Comment: It depends. If you pick specific fields when processing you can omit this. But if you pass $_POST as array somewhere deeper it might be good idea to perform this check.